# Icon is showing on wrong location in flutter map but showing the exact latlng where i am

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-maps

My latlng from this code is showing my exact location, but the icon is showing outside the country,I tried by printing my location and its showing the exact location but animating towards outside the country.

```
void getRideLiveLocationUpdates(){
        LatLng oldPos=LatLng(0,0);
        rideStreamSubscription= Geolocator.getPositionStream().listen((Position position) {
          currentPosition=position;
          myPostion=position;
          var rot = MapKitAssistant.getMarkerRotation(oldPos.latitude, oldPos.longitude, myPostion.latitude, myPostion.longitude);
    

      LatLng mPostion=LatLng(position.longitude,position.latitude);
      Marker animatingMarker=Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId("animating"),
        position: mPostion,
        icon: animatingMarkerIcon!,
        rotation:rot,
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: "Current Location"),


      );
      setState(() {
        CameraPosition cameraPosition=new CameraPosition(target: mPostion,zoom: 17);
        newRideGoogleMapController.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
        markersSet.removeWhere((marker) => marker.markerId.value=="animating");
        print("my longitude");
        print(mPostion.longitude);
        print("my latitude");
        print(mPostion.latitude);

        markersSet.add(animatingMarker);
      });
      oldPos=mPostion;

      updateRideDetail();
      String? rideRequestId=widget.rideDetails.ride_request_id;
      Map locMap={
        "latitude":currentPosition.latitude.toString(),
        "longitude":currentPosition.longitude.toString()


      };
      newRequestRef.child(rideRequestId!).child("driver_location").set(locMap);
    });
  }
```

Comment: kindly see it again

Comment: is this an english coaching class?

Comment: You get all for free ;-) Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide LatLng class? I think there is a mistake but not sure

Comment: bro LatLng is a built in class and i printed the latlng thats exact where my location is but its animating to the wrong location